# Proxy requests to node with apache except requests containing specific path

Tags: apache, codeigniter, mod-rewrite, proxy, reverse-proxy

I need all requests on my server to be proxied to node on port 8000 except requests containing /api/ci in their path.

This is my current config, the issue with it is that it is routing everything to port 8000, including the /api/ci requests instead of allowing them to hit the backend directly. For some reason the /api/ci rule is not being applied and being proxied instead. The backend is built in PHP with the Codeigniter framework.

```
ProxyRequests off
<Proxy *>
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all
</Proxy>

<Location /api/ci/>
    ProxyPass !
</Location>

<Location />
    ProxyPass http://localhost:8000/
    ProxyPassReverse http://localhost:8000/
</Location>
```

Comment: Try reversing the order of <Location> blocks

Comment: Tried that, same issue

Answer (score 0):

Do not add '/' at the end of your exception:

```
<Location /api/ci>
    ProxyPass !
</Location>
```

You could also use a wildcard like:

```
<Location /api/ci/*>
        ProxyPass !
</Location>
```

Comment: Tried both of these solutions, all urls are still getting proxied to node

Comment: Did you try the same outside of location blocks?